# ag grid scroll to newly created item and highlight the row

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid in angular for CRUD operation application. When I create a new item, it will update in the grid but once update the item scrollbar should scroll to the new item position and that new item row should be highlighted.

Expert advise please?

**HTML**

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-balham" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [rowSelection]="rowSelection" [rowData]="rowData" [suppressMenuHide]="true"  [rowDragManaged]="true"
     [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
      (rowClicked)='onRowClicked($event)' (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

**TS**

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([
      {
        headerName: "",
        field: "markedAsFavorite",
        minWidth: 50,
        maxWidth: 50,
        headerComponentParams: { menuIcon: "fa-star" },
        cellRendererFramework: DisciplinesCellComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
          ngTemplate: this.greetCell
        }
      },
      {
        headerName: "Disciplines",
        field: "name", valueGetter: (params) => params.data.name.en,
      },
      {
        headerName: "Market",
        field: "market", valueGetter: (params) => params.data.markets.name,
      },
      {
        headerName: "Description",
        field: "description", valueGetter: (params) => params.data.description.en
      }
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Can you show your *try/tried code*?

Comment: Code  posted. Looking for, If it is any default option in ag-grid or Do we need to create custom component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RowDataTransaction and ensureIndexVisible provided in ag-grid to achieve this.

```
  onAddNewRow(data: any) {
    if (this.gridOptions && this.gridOptions.api) {
      const addedRow = this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({
        add: [data]
      });
      addedRow.add[0].setSelected(true);
      this.gridOptions.api.ensureIndexVisible(addedRow.add[0].rowIndex, 'bottom');
    }
  }
```

Here updateRowDate will return an object with the structure of

```
interface RowDataTransaction {

    // Row Nodes added
    add: RowNode[];

    // Row Nodes removed
    remove: RowNode[];

    // Row Nodes updated
    update: RowNode[];
}
```

Since you are adding a single row you can access it from the element at the 0 index. By passing the index of the newly added row to the method ensureIndexVisible you can scroll down to that specific row.

Comment: Thank you. It is working fine but it always adding in bottom of the grid without sort order.  I would like to add in sort order. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm trying to make this work, but it seems that the new row isn't ready for editing, so the startEditingCell doesn't do anything. Is there a built in way to async await this?

Comment: Wow, just figured it out. There's `applyTransactionAsync` now. You can add a callback function that does whatever you need to do after the row is made